# Iterator in a while loop executes one more time than expected

Tags: ruby, while-loop, iterator

I am trying to create a code that runs until a person says `'BYE'` three consecutive times.

With the following code:

```
ask = gets.chomp
count = 0
while (count != 3)
  if (ask == 'BYE')
    puts 'HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
    count = count + 1
    ask = gets.chomp
  elsif (ask != ask.upcase)
    puts 'HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
    count = 0
    ask = gets.chomp
  else
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + rand(1930..1950).to_s + '!'
    count = 0
    ask = gets.chomp
  end
end
puts 'Goodbye for now'
```

I actually need to type `'BYE'` four times. Can someone point to how to fix it?

Comment: You do understand that 0,1,2,3 is four times correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to type BYE four times. Just three is enough. The fourth input can be anything.

```
BYE # input 1
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
BYE # input 2
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
BYE # input 3
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
nah, I give up # input 4
Goodbye for now
```

The problem with your code is that you request next input immediately after you have chosen a handler. Even if, by your logic, you're not going to need that input. So you'll have to rework this part.

Answer (score 1):

Putting `gets` only once at the beginning of the loop fixes it :

```
count = 0

while count != 3
    ask = gets.chomp

    if ask == 'BYE'
        puts 'HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
        count = count + 1
    elsif ask != ask.upcase
        puts 'HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
        count = 0
    else
        puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + rand(1930..1950).to_s + '!'
        count = 0
    end
end

puts 'Goodbye for now'
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w topc.rb 
a
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
A
NO, NOT SINCE 1931!
BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
BYEE
NO, NOT SINCE 1939!
BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Goodbye for now
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while (count != 3)` is so Javaish (no need for parentheses in Ruby) that I can't resist to write a more rubyesque solution. Not shorter, but more DRY, with more code that you are likely to see in Ruby programs, and certainly not exemplary, there are always many ways to do the same thing in Ruby.

```
class Strange
    def initialize(wanted)
        @answer = true
        @count  = 0
        @wanted = wanted # desired number of correct consecutive answers
    end

        # Increment @count if true, else reset to zero.
    def answer(boolean)
        @answer = boolean

        if boolean
        then # then is optional, but I like it
            @count = @count + 1
        else
            @count = 0
        end
    end

        # Write a message.
    def message(number)
        puts case number
        when 1 then 'HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!'
        when 2 then "NO, NOT SINCE #{rand(1930..1950)} !"
        else 'WHAT ?'
        end
    end

    def prompt
        print @answer ? 'Talk please > ' : 'Wrong answer, retry > '
        @ask = gets.chomp
    end

        # Recursively loop until the number of correct consecutive answers
        # corresponds to the desired number.
    def run
        prompt

        case
        when @ask == 'BYE'
            message 1
            answer(true)
        when @ask != @ask.upcase
            message 1
            answer(false)
        else
            message 2
            answer(false)
        end

        run unless @count == @wanted # recursive loop
    end
end # class Strange

Strange.new(3).run

puts 'Goodbye for now'
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
Talk please > xyz
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Wrong answer, retry > XYZ
NO, NOT SINCE 1935 !
Wrong answer, retry > BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Talk please > what ?
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Wrong answer, retry > BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Talk please > BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Talk please > BYE
HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!
Goodbye for now
```

Comment: Don't use ternary for control flow. :)

Comment: I consider it a code smell, yes (although can't find it in the ruby style guide). My reasoning is this: ternary operator is an "expression". It is weird to have an expression whose primary purpose is to cause side effects. Yes, technically `if` in ruby is an expression too, but it "looks" like a control flow statement and thus conveys a different message.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree it was an abuse of ternary. Good old `if then else` is clearer.

Comment: Only don't need `then` :)